# How to move a legend on an Altair mark_arc chart

Tags: altair

I want to move the legend to the top-left of the chart. Is that possible?

```
percentage_men_women = alt.Chart(men_women, title=alt.Title("Admissions men vs women 2014-2019")).mark_arc(innerRadius=50).encode(
    theta="Value",
    color="Gender:N",
    #legend=alt.Legend(title=None, orient="top-left")
).properties(width=20, height=10)
percentage_men_women
```

[image]